# MudDatePicker return right date date and save wrong date in database Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using a DatePicker in my project which return right date but when save it in database returned date is selected date -1 day.

MarkUp:

```
  <MudDatePicker  PickerVariant="PickerVariant.Dialog" Style="border-radius: 10px; border-color: #bdbdbd; colo: #4e607e; font-family: Calibri" Rounded="true" Label="Date" @bind-Date="MyDate"  DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

C# Code:

```
DateTime MyDate=DateTime.Now;
```

when select date from the picker returned the chosen date but save it in database as -1 day.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What is `MudDatePicker`? And how do you save the date? Have you tried debugging, or adding eg `Console.WriteLine(MyDate);` before saving and inspect what's written in the browser's console?

Comment: What is the value of `MyDate` when it is submitted to be saved?  What time zone is the database server in and the application server running in?  Depending on your database server, there's now `DateTimeOffset` to deal with timezone issues.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes I tried debugging and `MyDate` save the right date but in database no.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis `MyDate` save the right date but the problem is when saved in database be -1 day. I will try `DateTimeOffset` now.

Comment: Which means something is wrong in the code that writes to the database. Post *that* code along with the table schema. `DateTimeOffset` won't help if the database expects a `datetime` or `date`.  What do you want to store anyway? Local datetime? UTC datetime? Just the date? DateTime *and* Offset?

Comment: If your code converts to UTC before saving it's quite possible that the date will change as well. This will happen even in the UK now that they're in summer time (+1). That's not a problem, unless you try to treat the stored UTC datetime as a *local* datetime. In that case, even in the UK you'll get a different date part for 1 hour every day.

Comment: I tried `DateTimeOffset` and it is storing the date as array.

@PanagiotisKanavos when I tried debugging the date was right for the last method the date didn't change at all but when looked at the database it was -1 day. before I stored the date it was (9-8-2021T12:00:00Am +00.....) after stored in database it was (9-7-2021T21:00:00Pm!00.....)

Comment: `storing the date as array` not in any database I've worked with. SQL, the language, doesn't have arrays. Some database products do but require very specific syntax and C# code. And `9-8-2021T12:00:00Am +00` isn't a date value. In almost all databases (except SQLite) dates are separate, binary values. They're displayed by client tools either in the ISO format or as local date strings. What you posted is a string with a custom format that's not used by any country. Post your code and table schema, and clearly explain which database product and version is used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236899/discussion-between-sameeh-shadid-and-panagiotis-kanavos).

Comment: Even that custom format though shows a possible offset bug (among others). Is the offset `+03:00` on the server where the code runs? In that case the values are the same but one is the UTC value and the other is the local value for the exact same instant. If you add 3 hours to `2021-09-07 21:00` you get `2021-09-08 00:00`